# How to style individual elements created with array.map using styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

The goal is to be able to target each unique element in order to give it unique styling.

In my code the array in question is an array of objects, and each dummyElement will have an unique absolute position based on a value of the current item key, such as curr.longitude.

```
// dummyElement.styled.js file

export const dummyElement = styled.a`
  font-size: 20px;
`; // Styles all the dummyElements, how to style them individually?



// dummyElement.JSX file 

import { dummyElement } from "./dummyElement.styled";

<>
  props.dummyArray.map((current, index) => (
    <dummyElement
      key={index}
      href={"https://dummywebsite/" + current.value}
    >
      {current.value}
    </dummyElement>
  ))
</>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation. https://styled-components.com/
I think the solution comes in this way. Try it, and tell me if it works.

```js
/ dummyElement.styled.js file

export const dummyElement = styled.a`
  font-size: 20px;
  ${ props => props.longValue === 'someLongitudeValue' && css`
    background-color: white;
  `}
  ${ props => props.longValue === 'otherLongitudeValue' && css`
    background-color: green;
  `}
`; // Styles all the dummyElements, how to style them individually?



// dummyElement.JSX file 

import { dummyElement } from "./dummyElement.styled";

<>
  props.dummyArray.map((current, index) => (
    <dummyElement
      key={index}
      href={"https://dummywebsite/" + current.value}
      longValue={current.long}
    >
      {current.value}
    </dummyElement>
  ))
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in values for dynamic styling through the `id` property and then parse them in the `dummyElement` styled component like this:

```js
// Define your dynamic styled components something like this
export const DummyElement = styled.div`
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: ${props => Number(props.id.split('-')[2])}px;
  background-color: ${props => props.id.split('-')[1]};
  color: #FBE7FD;
`;

// Then when using the DummyComponent do something like this
<DummyElement id='dummy1-coral-100' />
<DummyElement id='dummy2-indianred-50' />
<DummyElement id='dummy3-pink-20' />
```